# What's the flavor profile of Bravo hops?

Tags: hops

Have you used Bravo hops? What kind of bitterness/aroma do they confer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used them myself, but since no one else is answering, I'll say that I've heard good things about Bravo, along these lines:

- Bitters well, a bit like Simcoe, but
  cleaner.
- A blend of
  earthy/fruity/spice for aroma, sort
  of like Warrior.
- Less Citrus in aroma
  and taste than, say, Centennial.

One person said it made a great single-hop beer, and one said it was a little weak as a single-hop, and needed to be blended with other hops for character.